# Report individual changes to data

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I need to produce a daily extract on the individual changes to a dataset.
So, there are 14 tables containing product and customer information and the extract must only show records from each table that are newly entered or records that have had any column updated.

What would be the best way to do this please?

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2, and develop in C#.

Comment: Maybe [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wanted to track user's changes so I could recover from their mistakes, I created a denormalized 'audit' table with all of the pks and created triggers to add rows to it whenever a base table was modified.

one of the triggers was:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[programGroupProcedureCodeModRateDate_insdel]
   ON  [dbo].[programGroupProcedureCodeModRateDate] 
   AFTER insert, delete
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into archive
        select 
            procedureCodeModRate, 
            null as programGroup_svc, null as serviceID, null as serviceDesc, null as isExcludedFromIncreases,
            null as unitID,
            null as rateMaskID, null as programGroup_unpub, null as isUnpublished,
            programGroup_rate, startID, Rate, isDiscontinued, comment, 
            getdate() as lastupdated, Current_User as lastUpdatedBy, 'i' as operation
        from inserted

    insert into archive
        select 
            procedureCodeModRate, 
            null as programGroup_svc, null as serviceID, null as serviceDesc, null as isExcludedFromIncreases,
            null as unitID,
            null as rateMaskID, null as programGroup_unpub, null as isUnpublished,
            programGroup_rate, startID, Rate, isDiscontinued, comment, 
            getdate() as lastupdated, Current_User as lastUpdatedBy, 'd' as operation
        from deleted
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a trigger to another table, and any Inserts or Updates get logged in the other table with the field that changed and when the change occurred.